# Generate rows in a DataFrame with rvs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that i would like to add some rows at the end. The problem is that the number can be variable, and can be high. So I want to use some method to generate rows with the same value. I think that with rvs can work, but for the moment i didn't achieved.

So i will put some simple example.

I have this DataFrame.

```
    a   b 
0   0   8 
1   1   4
2   3   5
```

And i would like to obtain a new DataFrame with:

```
    a   b 
0   0   8 
1   1   4
2   3   5
3   2   3
4   2   3
```

In this example, i put that we added only two new rows but i can be 1000.

So how i can do it? its possible with rvs?

Comment: Where does `rvs` come into play? You're looking to randomly generate a new row then duplicate that `n` times? Or there are some other additional requirements of the new rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the rows before appending:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 3}, 'b': {0: 8, 1: 4, 2: 5}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'b': [3]})

df1.append([df2]*10, ignore_index=True)

    a  b
0   0  8
1   1  4
2   3  5
3   2  3
4   2  3
5   2  3
6   2  3
7   2  3
8   2  3
9   2  3
10  2  3
11  2  3
12  2  3
```